# Add Google DFP ad unit heading ("Advertisement") to all the ads with a white background and a padding

Tags: javascript, css, google-dfp, google-ads-api

We have Google DFP ad units on our site and we need to add an "Advertisement" text heading and a white background with padding to all the ads. The design should be as follows.

[image]

Can someone please help me to achieve the above ?

Comment: this might interests you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57796067/how-can-i-hide-another-div-on-collapsed-ad-manager-ads/57817018#57817018

Comment: @rabsom Thank you very much. I will check the above link :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do so, i will use css. Let's suppose all your ad slots have a class "adstyle" :

```
<div id="banner" class="adstyle">
here is where the GAM iframe will be inserted
</div>

<style>
.adstyle {
  width:auto;
  background: #fff;
  padding:20px;
  position:relative;
 }

.adstyle:before {
  content : '- ADVERTISEMENT -';
  display : block;
  witdh: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  font-weigt:14px;
  text-align : center;
  margin : 0 0 20px 0;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I have already done this using CSS. Many Thanks !! :-)